# Asterisk Out Password in HTML (using Ruby on Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, passwords

I'm a newby at web programming, and even newer to ruby on rails. What is the best way of asterisking out or "hiding" a new password entered by a user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well it's not rails. It's html.

```
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

However with rails, you can use an helper and generate that html field automatically in your view :

```
<%= password_field :password %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You use an input field with the type "password":

```
<input type="password" name="ThePassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="password">`

But if you intend for this to be something people will actually use, keep in mind that security goes a lot further than that and can actually be quite tricky.